# Telepathic Teenage Boy Alone on Planet Who Hears Alien Voice in His Head

Tags: story-identification, aliens, childrens-novel, telepathy

I remember this juvenile Sci-Fi novel I read sometime when I was a teenager; so it probably was written in the 1960s, or possibly in the early 1970s.

One of the central characters is an adolescent boy who was either stranded or shipwrecked on a planet, and he has been alone all of his life except for a voice he hears in his head. It turns out this voice belongs to an alien creature who has been guiding and mentoring this boy all his life. They essentially have a telepathic connection.

Meanwhile, across the galaxy on another planet, there is an adolescent girl who is also telepathic, but from what I remember she lives in an oppressive society. She must keep her telepathy secret. Somehow the girl and boy found out about each other and start communicating with each other telepathically across the galaxy.

And the alien voice in his head is not so nice after all...The girl must travel in a spaceship with an older man who finds out about her telepathy so they can rescue the boy from the alien who is trying to mind control him. That's the gist of the story.

Comment: I haven't read Lord of the Stars although this theme was covered by John Wyndham several times, most notably in his novelet Chocky published 6 years earlier. A young boy begins to develop heightened intelligence, maths &logic skills much to everyones surprise - in reality he is being tutored and fed the information by an alien who is using him as a conduit to communicate with Earth. Midwich Cuckoos 1957 and The Chrysalids 1955 also explore the theme, the latter includes an adolescent girl in an oppressive society keeping her powers secret whilst communicating with others across the planet.

Answer (score 7):

My guess is "Lord of the Stars" by Jeff and Jean Sutton.

http://www.librarything.com/work/4472490
http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1349541.Lord_Of_The_Stars

Danny grew up alone on an alien planet guided by the telepathic thoughts of unseen Zandro. Finally he makes mental contact with humans on another world and learns he is being used in a plot to conquer the universe.